# Allow only certain users to access the web page using php and sql server

Tags: php, sql-server

I am working on a php based web app for a university. As the university has its own login system,
I would  still like to restrict the web page to only certain users who are in my database.

```
My ms sql database looks like this:
Id  UserId
1    ma580
2    am555
```

I have added university's login page to my web app and it works perfectly fine. But it can be used by any
user that has university's id and password. 
I want to restrict it to only those users who I put in my database.

I tried something like this:

queries.php

```
Class Queries{
public static function getUser($ID){
           $conn = DB::databaseConnection();
        $sql = "SELECT User FROM Admins WHERE ID = :Id";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':ID', $ID);
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        } else {
            return null;
        } 

}
```

header.php

```
require_once './functions/queries.php';
$ID = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "id");
$User = Queries::getUser($ID);

session_start();

if($_SESSION('User')!== $User){
    header('Location: index.php');
}
```

This code doesn't work. When I try to login with a different Id (which is not present in the database) the page goes blank. I am new to php, any help with this one would be appreciated. Thank You

Comment: @SeanLange What do you mean? OP is using parameterized queries... Am I missing something?

Comment: AAM, I believe `$_SESSION('User')` should be `$_SESSION['User']` - but I also don't see where you are declaring this.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton oh dear....you are right. Oops.

Comment: You want to use a login page and its database (that is out of your control since it's your university's) for your web app? I don't see this possible without talking to your university's website admin and setting up a SSO or make them give you tokens for successful login that you can check on your web app.

Comment: @CurseStacker yes I got the access to the university login system from the admin, so now anyone from university can login and view the page with his id and password, hence I want to restrict it to only a few users.

Comment: Create another table that saves the ID of the user (and maybe his permissions to your web application). Now on your web application add another layer of verification after login. Check from this new table if the user exist, if not, redirect back to your university's login page.

Comment: @CurseStacker yeah that’s what I tried to do in header.php. Can you check it and make corrections to the above code. Or if you could give any examples, it would be of great help to me.

Comment: @CurseStacker In my database, the column ‘User’ saves the id of the user.

Comment: Sorry I know very little php so I'd rather leave it to the experts on this field.